# Is it secure to pass the DB query to AzureML as a global parameter?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

When using AzureMLBatchExecution activity in Azure Data Factory, is it secure to pass the DB query as a global parameter to the AzureML web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you talk about "secure", are you worried about secure transmission between AML and ADF, or secure storage of your DB query information? For the former, all communication between these two services will be done with HTTPS. For the latter, our production storage has its strict access control. Besides, we only log the count of the global parameters and never the values. I believe it's secure to pass your DB query as a global parameter to the AzureML web service.

Comment: Is the DB query encrypted when it is being passed as a global parameter from ADF to AzureML?